How do I run 2 different functions from 1 file with 2 different command line prompts in Node.js?
I have a .js file in my project that imports an NPM package and has 2 functions that use that package:
//replacePaths.js
import {replaceInFile} from 'replace-in-file';
async function replace() {
    const options = {
        files: 'src/**/*.jsx',
        from: 'dev/svgs/icons-main.svg',
        to: 'staging/media/svgs/icons-main.svg',
    };

    try {
        const results = await replaceInFile(options);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error occurred:', error);
    }
}

async function revert() {
    const options = {
        files: 'src/**/*.jsx',
        from: 'staging/media/svgs/icons-main.svg',
        to: 'dev/svgs/icons-main.svg',
    };

    try {
        const results = await replaceInFile(options);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error occurred:', error);
    }
}
module.exports = {
    replace,
    revert
};

I want to be able to run these functions from the command line. I've Googled around and to do this it seems I just add the following to my package.json file:
"scripts": {
    ...
    "replace": "node replacePaths.js replace",
    "revert" : "node replacePaths.js revert",
    ...
}

I the first of these in the command line as such: npm run replace, but I got the error ReferenceError: module is not defined in ES module scope.
Googling that, I changed the exports part to:
export default replace;
export default revert;

and tried again. I didn't get any errors, but instead just got the line node replacePaths.js replace printed in the console.
I can run the functions by removing the export part and just having replace() or revert() on the JS file, but that's not helpful to me if I want to have 2 functions on the same file.
Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction?

no point exporting in that file, since nothing is importing it. you don't call your functions anywhere - you'll need to use process.argv to get the command line arguments, then some logic to call the appropriate function

@JaromandaX ok, but how do I run those functions from the command line?

you'll need to use process.argv to get the command line arguments, then some logic to call the appropriate function

await ({ replace, revert })[process.argv.at(-1)]?.(); at the end of the file will do it

Thanks. Want to make that an answer so I can accept?

Just did it while you were commenting :D

here's the simplest answer - to run the function named on the command line
import {replaceInFile} from 'replace-in-file';
async function replace() {
    // snip
}

async function revert() {
    // snip
}
// add this to actually run a function
await ({ replace, revert })[process.argv.at(-1)]?.();


// file: app.js
const functionOne = () => {
    console.log("Function One Executed");
};

const functionTwo = () => {
    console.log("Function Two Executed");
};

const args = process.argv.slice(2);

if (args[0] === 'functionOne') {
    functionOne();
} else if (args[0] === 'functionTwo') {
    functionTwo();
}


Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

To run a different command depending on a command-line argument, your top-level code could be structured something like this:
const [,,command] = process.argv;

try {
  if (command === 'replace') {
      await replace();
  } else if (command === 'revert') {
      await revert();
  } else {
      console.error('Unknown command. Use "replace" or "revert".');
  }
} catch (e) {
  console.error(e);
}

Examples of running it:
node replacePaths.js replace
node replacePaths.js revert

